# Replace image source with RegExp where another attribute comes first

Tags: javascript, html, regex, replace, tags

I have this for exapmple

```
<img style="height:375; width:500;" src="../img/ris1_1.jpg" ALIGN="center">
<img src="img/ris1_2.jpg" style="height:375; width:500;" ALIGN="center">
```

I used this RegExp to replace src tag:

```
(?<=(<img src=['"]))[^"']+
```

But it finds only imgs where src comes right after

Also I need to replace only relative paths, not absolute. So if I have absolute path in src I must not replace it.

P.S. Yeah! I've done, thanks Shomz for that! Just do this:

```
tag.replace(/(img[^>]*src=['"])+(?!http:\/\/)\s*([^'"]*)/gi,"$1http://mydomain.com/$2");
```

Comment: Instead of using a regex why not just select the element and update its `.src` property

Comment: Move the src attribute after the img tag in the first one?

Comment: I can't replace src with .src because I search it in text, parsed from page. Also I can't move src attribute.

Comment: (?<=(<img[^>]*src=['"]))[^"']+ is not working(

Comment: JS regex supports lookbehinds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `tag` is your tag, you can do:

```
tag.replace(/(img[^>]*src=['"])+(\s*)[^'"]*/g, '$1REPLACED.jpg');
```

UPDATE

To omit absolute urls, use this regex `(img[^>]*src=['"])+(?!http:\/\/)\s*[^'"]*`.

Comment: It's very good solution! And how to replace only relative paths?

Comment: Thank you! It is working! :) But I still can't add old src, such as "img/ris1.jpg" to replacement...

Comment: You're welcome! Also, you might need to take care of `../` in the relative paths if you're just switching domains.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just selecting with the search string only the value of src attribute of an img element, use the capturing search string `(<img.*?src=['"])[^"']+` and start the replace string with `\1` to keep everything from `<img` to `"` or `'` on replace.

Of course you could simply use search string `(?<=src=['"])[^"']+` if the src attribute is not used in any other element than img.

The suggestion by Tony is also good. With searching for `(<img)(.+?)( src=["'][^"']+["'])` and using as replace string `\1\3\2` it is possible to first standardize all img elements by moving src attribute to first position after `<img`.